# Using node request or axios with streams to download and unpack file not handling back pressure as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, axios, zlib

We have a large file around 6 GB that is decompressed to 64 GB size (OS image) that we need to download using http. We are using either node's request library or axios. File is downloaded and unpacked (piped) on the fly using following code:

```
 const downloadUsingHttp = (downloadUrl, destinationPath) => {enter code here
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const unpackedPathWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath);

        let totalDownloadSize = 64023257088;
        let downloadedSize = 0;
        let lastProgressSent = 0;
        
        axios({
          method: 'get',
          url: downloadUrl,
          responseType: 'stream',
          auth: {
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass'
          },
            withCredentials: true
         }).then(function (response) {
            response.data
              .on('data', chunk => {
                if (totalDownloadSize === 0) {
                  return;
                }
                downloadedSize += chunk.length;
                const progress = Math.floor((downloadedSize / totalDownloadSize) * 100);
    
                if (progress % 5 !== 0) {
                  return;
                }
    
                if (lastProgressSent === progress) {
                  return;
                }
    
                lastProgressSent = progress;
                console.log('Copy progress ', progress + ' %')
              })
              .pipe(zlib.createUnzip())
              .pipe(unpackedPathWriteStream)

        }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err.message)
        });
    
        unpackedPathWriteStream
          .on('error', err => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
          }).on('end', () => {
            resolve();
          })
   })
};

downloadUsingHttp(
  'https://example.com/storage/file.raw.gz',
  '/data/downloaded-and-unziped.raw'
);
```

Machine we are running this code has 2 GB of RAM. When this code is ran, the issue appearing is that machine runs out of RAM memory, at about 15% progress and the node application crashes. Sometimes even the whole machine becomes unresponsive and needs to be rebooted.

So it seems like [back pressure handling](https://nodejs.org/es/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/#too-much-data-too-quickly) implemented trough .pipe() on streams is not working in this case. For instance, when not downloading file trough http (with request or axios library), but doing it with readable and writable streams, doing same operations of copying and unziping on the fly using pipe method is working and there is no memory exhaustion.

**Also, it is important to mention that this issue only appears when performing http download in a local network (local development environment).**

Any help would be appriciated.

**Update**

We've tried throttling the stream to 100 KB/s and it seems to work in terms that there was no increased RAM memory usage. When changed to 1 MB/s usage is increased and eventually application brakes. We've used `stream-throttle` library to try this.

Comment: what's the difference between your local development environment and prod?

Comment: I don't have much experience with pipes, but what about loading the file in chunks and feeding them into the pipe one at a time. then loading the next chunk. So the pipe would only have to deal with as little as a few MB of data at once.

Comment: @DanStarns diff is that in local env, local network is used instead of public (internet) that is used for production, so the download is faster and that probably has affect on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the node  memory limit? `node --max-old-space-size=2048`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with pipes, but what about loading the file in chunks and feeding them into the pipe one at a time. then loading the next chunk. So the pipe would only have to deal with as little as a few MB of data at once.

I imagine something like this:

```
const downloadUsingHttp = (downloadUrl, destinationPath, chunkSize = 10<<20) => {
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(destinationPath);
  const unzip = zlib.createUnzip();

  const auth = {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
  };

  const nextChunk = () => axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: downloadUrl,
      responseType: 'stream',
      auth: auth,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        Range: `bytes=${offset}-${(offset += chunkSize)}`
      }
    }).then(downThePipe);

  const downThePipe = response => {
    console.log("progress %i%%   ( %i / %i bytes )", offset / length * 100, offset, length);
    response.data.pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream);

    return offset < length ? nextChunk() : null;
  };

  let offset = 0, length;
  return axios({
    method: "HEAD",
    url: downloadUrl,
    auth: auth,
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(response => {
    length = response.headers["Content-Length"];
    return nextChunk();
  });
};



downloadUsingHttp(
  'https://example.com/storage/file.raw.gz',
  '/data/downloaded-and-unziped.raw'
);
```

Maybe, if the download is still too fast, you'd want to delay loading the `nextChunk()` untill after the `pipe()`work is done. But again, it's been a while that I've worked with these pipes.

Comment: Is `responseType: 'stream'` only valid when using Node / server-side requests?

Comment: @JoeH I would have thought so, but I don't find where axios would say that. The only exception to responseTypes i found mentioned is that `responseType: "blob"` is only available in the browser. The other ones are listed as if they work in both environments, browser and Node.

Comment: It turns out that `responseType: 'stream'` isn't supported by axios in the browser. I am not sure if they will configure a wrapper for the `fetch` API in the future.  The issue is still open in GitHub : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479

Comment: @Thomas-  could you please answer this question, Thanks ---    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065615/how-to-download-file-with-axios-in-node-js-and-write-to-the-response